# Java printing empty array error

Tags: java, arrays

This is my very simple code, with data being an empty double array

```
private void findLast(){
    double empty[] = new double[0];
    if(data == empty){
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(" Array is empty");
    }else{
        System.out.println(data[data.length-1]);
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

My question is, shouldn't the "throw" and "if" stop the "else" from running? And how do I fix the code so it runs properly?

Comment: `0 - 1 = -1` and there is no such as -1 index.

Comment: but shouldn't it not run?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by `it should not run`?

Comment: shoudnt the else part not happen if the "if" part is true?

Comment: JohnKasich, no, thats not how it does.

Comment: What is `data`? Why are you comparing `data` to some temporary array you just created? Why are you throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when that isn't really the error?

Comment: "equals" also doesn't get me what I want. Do you know any way I can get this code to work?

Comment: data = new double[0]; is all I have for it. It's really just any empty array

Comment: Refer to 4castle's answer thats how it looks like.

Comment: @JohnKasich_2016 What is data here ??

Answer (score 3):

`==` tests for reference equality for reference types such as arrays.

- `empty == empty` is `true`
- `empty == new double[0]` is `false`.

If you need to find if an array is empty, use:

```
if (data.length == 0) {
```

Comment: I've tried that too, but then I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:  Array is empty"

Comment: @JohnKasich_2016 Isn't that the output you wanted? If you don't want an exception to be thrown, then don't throw one.

Comment: @JohnKasich_2016 ofcs your Array is empty.

Comment: I get it as an error message, and the rest of the code doesn't run. I want it to print "Array is empty" and then for the rest of the code to run

Comment: Then use `System.out.println("Array is empty");`!

Comment: @JohnKasich_2016 I suggest post more code. It seems that you mess it up.

Comment: ahh yes replacing "throw" with "System.out.print" worked, I guess the problem was with the "throw".

Answer (score 1):

In java, the == operator checks if the two variables reference the same object, not if the two objects that the variables reference have equivalent values. So, even if both empty and data are double arrays of size 0, data == empty will never be true because they don't reference the same object.

As a side note, I'm not really sure there's any good reason for you to be doing this and an array of size 0 doesn't have an element at length - 1. If empty has zero elements, what is the point of creating it? if it doesn't have zero elements and you want to know if there is nothing stored into it, then you should know that arrays always have something stored in them after being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(data.length==empty.length)
{
    throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(" Array is empty");
}else{
    System.out.println(data[data.length-1]);
}
```